# Does the Mindstorms EV3 software work on macOS Sierra?

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, software, compatibility, mac

I guess this is a **continuation** of these two questions:

[Does the Mindstorms EV3 software run on OS X El Capitan?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6775/does-the-mindstorms-ev3-software-run-on-os-x-el-capitan)

[Is the LEGO Midstorms EV3 software compatible with OS X yosemite?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/is-the-lego-midstorms-ev3-software-compatible-with-os-x-yosemite)

macOS Sierra was just released, and I want to upgrade. Will there be issues with the software, or will it work properly?

My Mac: Retina MBP 13", Early 2015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a Mac Mini with macOS Sierra, and the LEGO software works on it for me.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition was crashing on startup (latest Mac OS X Sierra du jour: 10.12.6 16G1113) — presumably (from [callisto's answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/8908/9482)) because my installed version of Mono was too recent. I [uninstalled Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/#uninstalling-mono-on-mac-os-x) by typing the following commands in a Terminal:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.mono-MDK.pkg
sudo rm -rf /etc/paths.d/mono-commands`

Afterwards, I uninstalled and reinstalled LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition from its [official source](https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/download-software) and I could successfully run it. FWIW, the version of Mono that LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition installs for itself is 2.10.9:

```
# ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  12 root  wheel  408  8 mai  2012 2.10.9
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    6 25 nov 12:46 Current -> 2.10.9
```

Answer (score 2):

Beware though. If you install Xamarin on your OSX machine, it will grab the latest Mono framework which is NOT compatible with the EV3 software (I don't recall which MONO version is used by EV3 software).

I have contacted Lego support a few times, and they are not going to update their OSX software. You will either have to then use a different machine or a VM to run the EV3 software.

Comment: Could you please share your insight on exactly which versions of Mono are compatible?

Comment: IIRC EV3 Software uses Mono 2.10.9

Comment: FYI, LEGO has (mostly) fixed this issue. Both versions of Mono can be installed side-by-side and the LEGO software will now continue to work even when you upgrade Xamarin/Visual Studio for Mac. I think that installing the LEGO software may temporarily break other Mono software because it sets the old version of Mono to the default, but you can just reinstall the newer Mono and all your programs should work.